# # of bars since a historical high was x amount higher than current high

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am looking to mark a historical bar the High of which was - say - 0.10 USD bigger than the current bar's High.

`ta.barssince()` comes to mind, however, how would the condition be defined?

This gives me incomprehensible results:

```
lh(diff) =>
    ret = -1                               // return -1 if nothing found
    for a = 1 to 100                       // compare against max 100 historical highs
        if na(high[a])                     // take care of pre-historical bars
            break
        else 
            if high[a] >= high + diff      // compare current high against historical highs
                ret := a                   // break if found
                break

    ret                                    // ... and return offset (or -1)

off = lh(0.10)
plotchar(off != -1, title = "LH", char = "▲", location = location.abovebar, size = size.tiny, offset = off)
```

Bars are marked with ▲ regardless of whether or not the condition is met. This happens in long sequences of many bars/no bars marked.